# Create new binary variable based on multiple binary columns in other data frame with same index

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a data frame with distance values (km) between forest i (first column), and facility j (top row):

```
Df1=
Forest,Bell Bay,Surrey Hills,Smithton,Hobart
Coupe1,158,194,10,49
Coupe2,156,169,71,84
Coupe3,10,186,101,163
Coupe4,47,194,134,139
Coupe5,144,161,135,56
Coupe6,27,127,134,36
Coupe7,114,104,143,113
Coupe8,71,170,190,140
Coupe9,194,154,173,128
Coupe10,46,194,92,36
```

I have maximum distance parameter Dmax = 100 km

I have created a  data frame with binary values. If the distance between forest and facility is <= Dmax then 1, else 0. The data frame looks like this:

```
Df2=
Forest,Bell Bay,Surrey Hills,Smithton,Hobart
Coupe1,0,0,1,1
Coupe2,0,0,1,1
Coupe3,1,0,0,0
Coupe4,1,0,0,0
Coupe5,0,0,0,1
Coupe6,1,0,0,1
Coupe7,0,0,0,0
Coupe8,1,0,0,0
Coupe9,0,0,0,0
Coupe10,1,0,1,1
```

I have another data frame with supply float values that looks like this: (note that forests or index are the same)

```
Df3=
Forest,Supply
Coupe1,6000
Coupe2,1000
Coupe3,9000
Coupe4,3000
Coupe5,3000
Coupe6,4000
Coupe7,9000
Coupe8,7000
Coupe9,5000
Coupe10,3000
```

I wanna create another data frame (or extra column in the previous data frame [‘Binary’]) with binary parameters, that is 1 if forest i is within Dmax of **ANY facility j**. The data frame should look like this:

```
Df3=
Forest,Supply, Binary
Coupe1,6000,1
Coupe2,1000,1
Coupe3,9000,1
Coupe4,3000,1
Coupe5,3000,1
Coupe6,4000,1
Coupe7,9000,0
Coupe8,7000,1
Coupe9,5000,0
Coupe10,3000,1
```

Note that for Coupe 7 and 9, the binary is 0 because both forests are more than 100 km away from Bell Bay, Surrey Hills, Smithton, Hobart facilities according to that first data frame.
What is the best way to formulate this?

If there is 1 in row Forest, then Df3['Binary'] =1, else 0

eg.

```
for i in Df2
if Coupe1,0,0,1,1 
then 1 in Df3['Binary']

if Couple7, 0,0,0,0 
then 0 in Df3['Binary']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since both `Df2` and `Df3` have same row sequence, you can do:

```
Df3['binary'] = Df2.iloc[:,1:].sum(1).gt(0)*1
```

In case, the row sequence is different in `Df2` & `Df3`, you can do:

```
Df3['binary'] = Df3['Forest'].map(Df2.set_index('Forest').sum(1).gt(0)*1)
```

Comment: I tried the following for same row df's: 
```df3['Binary'] = df2.iloc[:,0:len(df2.columns)].max(axis=1)```